# Construct a vector bundle parametrized by Ext classes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let me first mention a motivationg example. To explain a naive moduli space of vector bundles would be non-separated [here](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf), Huybrechts constructed a vector bundle on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb A^1$ in the following way: first, since $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal O(1),\mathcal O(-1)) = H^0(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O(-2)) = k$, there exists a family of extensions $$0 \to \mathcal O(-1) \to E_\lambda \to \mathcal O(1) \to 0$$ for $\lambda \in k$ (note: if $\lambda \neq 0$, then $E_\lambda \cong \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O$). Then, he argues that we can construct a vector bundle $E$ on $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb A^1$ such that $E|_{\mathbb P^1 \times \lambda} \cong E_\lambda$ (which leads to non-separated of a moduli space, should it exist). I think in this particular case, I can explicitly construct such a vector bundle by parametrizing gluing by hand, but I am not exactly sure how to use the ext class parametrization abstractly and wondering if there is a general procedure to construct such a vector bundle on the product of a variety and an affine space parmeterized by the ext classes.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: More explicitly, my most general question is the following:
Let $X$ be a nice space, say, a smooth projective variety and consider vector bundles $E,F$ on $X$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(E,F) = k$. Can we construct a vector bundle $G$ on $X\times \mathbb A^1$ such that $G|_{X \times \lambda} =G_\lambda$, where $G_\lambda$ is the extension corresponding to $\lambda \in k = \operatorname{Ext}^1(E,F)$?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ is the group of extensions?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand how we can construct an isomorphism between the Ext group in the sense of a derived functor and in the sense of Yoneda, but I was not sure Huybretchts's argenuent of construction a vector bundle on $X\times \mathbb A^1$ works for any reasonable $X$ and any pair of vector bundles $E,F$ with $Ext^1(E,F) = k$. (It is possible that I am missing something basic about the isomorphism if my comment does not really make sense)

Comment: Have a look at the paper "Universal families of extensions" by Herbert Lange (Journal of Algebra 83, 101-112, (1983)). The construction of a family of extensions you are looking for is in the paper. See the Introduction and Remark 3.5.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\lambda\in k$, then let
$$E_\lambda=\bigoplus_{e\in\mathbb Z}(E_\lambda)_{(e)},$$
where
$$(E_\lambda)_{(e)}=k\{x^{e-1},x^{e-2}y,\dots,y^{e-1}\}\oplus k\{\widetilde x^{e+1},\dots,\widetilde y^{e+1}\},$$
and the graded $k[x,y]$-module structure is:
$$\begin{align*}
x\cdot x^my^n&=x^{m+1}y^n\\
y\cdot x^my^n&=x^my^{n+1}\\
x\cdot\widetilde x^m\widetilde y^n&=\widetilde x^{m+1}\widetilde y^n\\
y\cdot\widetilde x^m\widetilde y^n&=\begin{cases}
\widetilde x^{m+1}\widetilde y^n-\lambda x^{m-1}&\text{if }n=0\\
\widetilde x^{m+1}\widetilde y^n&\text{if }n>0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
We have $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)\to E_\lambda$ is given by $x^my^n\mapsto x^my^n$, and $E_\lambda\to\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ is given by $x^my^n\mapsto0,\widetilde x^m\widetilde y^n\mapsto x^my^n$.

The category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb A^1=\mathrm{Proj}\ k[x_0,x_1]\times \mathrm{Spec}\ k[t]$ is isomorphic to graded modules of $k[t,x_0,x_1]$, where $|t|=0$ and $|x_0|=|x_1|=1$. Then the vector bundle $E$ is given by
$$E=\bigoplus_{e\in\mathbb Z}(E_\lambda)_{(e)}[t],$$
where the action is given as above.

**Remark:** For $\lambda\ne0$ there is an isomorphism $\mathcal O^2\simeq E_\lambda$ given by
$$\begin{align*}
(E_\lambda)_{(e)}=k\{x^{e-1},x^{e-2}y,\dots,y^{e-1}\}\oplus k\{\widetilde x^{e+1},\dots,\widetilde y^{e+1}\}&\simeq k\{x_1^e,\dots,y_1^e\}\oplus k\{x_2^e,\dots,y_2^e\}\\
f(x,y)&\mapsto (x_1f(x_1,y_1),y_2f(x_2,y_2))\\
\widetilde x^m&\mapsto (0,-\lambda x_2^{m-1})\\
\widetilde x^m\widetilde y^n(n>0)&\mapsto (\lambda x_1^my_1^{n-1},0).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I am wondering if you have a more coordinate-free approach to the construction so that this construction can be generalized to reasonable $X$ together with vector bundles $E,F$ with $Ext^1(E,F) = k$ or would you think this is a very specific construction for $X=\mathbb P^1$, $E= O(-1)$ and $F = O(1)$?